# Joining on a Select Distinct in MySQL reorders by joined table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I've looked around for an answer to this but I'm not finding it. I have a site with articles stored in an article table and writers in the user table. I wanted to get a list of authors ordered by how recently they'd written an article.

This gives me the User ids:

```
SELECT distinct a.user_id 
FROM `article` as a 
ORDER BY a.id desc
```

The problem is that as soon as I try to bring the names in by joining the order changes so that it's by user id. I've tried this:

```
SELECT distinct a.user_id, u.name 
FROM `article` as a 
LEFT JOIN user as u on u.id  = a.user_id 
ORDER BY a.id desc, u.id desc
```

and

```
SELECT distinct a.user_id, u.name 
FROM `article` as a 
LEFT JOIN user as u on u.id  = a.user_id 
ORDER BY u.id desc, a.id desc
```

but both alter the order of the names. I'm obviously doing something stupid, but what?

Comment: You want to sort by how recently they wrote an article, but are sorting on an ID field. Why not a "ArticleWrittenDate" field or something?

Comment: You're right, of course: There is a written_on datetime field but there's never a great deal of discrepancy between the published date and the id field and I was trying to pare things down for simplicity and new the answer I got could be easily adapted in any case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that DISTINCT happens to work with ORDER BY in your first example is a fluke, and not standard SQL. You need something like this:

```
SELECT a.user_id, u.name 
  FROM article a 
  LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = a.user_id 
  GROUP BY a.user_id
  ORDER BY MAX(a.id) desc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That definitely works and I understand it too. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT a.user_id, u.name 
FROM `article` a 
LEFT JOIN user u on u.id = a.user_id 
GROUP BY a.user_id
ORDER BY a.id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ORDER BY sorts the rows by either the User ID and/or Article ID (depending on the example).

If you want reliable sorting by name, then include the u.name field in the ORDER BY fields.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
select users.id, articles.id, max(articles.created_at) as recent_date
  from users
  left join articles on users.id = articles.user_id
  group by articles.id
  order by recent_date
```

Not sure what exactly your fields are named and all, but this should point you in the right direction.

You got a lot of answers to choose from... I believe the key to what you're asking is use of the aggregate function MAX() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max

Answer (score 0):

this is postgres syntax, but you can easily translate it into mysql

```
select u.*, q.last_article_id 
   from user u
      inner join (
        select a.user_id, max(a.id) as last_article_id
           from article a
           group by a.user_id
      ) q
      on u.id = a.q.id
   order by q.last_article_id desc
```